# NET CORE 3.1 MVC HttpPost Controller action gets a NULL parameter on form submit in view

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

I submit a register form in an MVC view, but in the controller when debugging the RegisterViewModel param is always NULL.

[image]
[image]

Few questions please:

> 1. Why are the fields NULL for the RegisterViewModel param in the controler?
> 2. Is it ok to use RAZOR PAGES and MVC VIEWS in the same project, a mix of
>    them?
> 3. Why are the tag helpers (such as "asp-for") not colored green by the Intellisense (The are blue instead in Register.chtml)?

The view:

```
@model MyProjectNamespace.Data.ViewModels.RegisterModel

@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
    ViewBag.Title = "User Registration";
}

<h1>User Registration</h1>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">

    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Email</label>
                    <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" type="text" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Password</label>
                    <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" type="password" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Confirm Password</label>
                    <input asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" type="password" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Company</label>
                    <input asp-for="CompanyID" class="form-control" type="text"/>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The controller:

```
namespace MyProjectNamespace.Controllers
{
    //[AllowAnonymous]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager;

        public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
                                 SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager  )
        {
            this.userManager = userManager;
            this.signInManager = signInManager;
        }

        // only one page load, NOT submit
        //[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }


        //answers on submit
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel registerViewModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //create new user
                var user = new ApplicationUser
                {
                    UserName = registerViewModel.Email,
                    Email = registerViewModel.Email
                };

                var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, registerViewModel.Password);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false); // create cookie that only lasts for the session
                    return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
                }

                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Description); // these errors are added in the view by asp-validation-summary="All"
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // re-render the register view and display errors
            }

            return View(registerViewModel);
        }
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            //services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            //    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            //services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            //    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

            // added for mvc
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                // added for razor pages routing
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();

                // added for mvc routing 
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                     name: "default",
                     pattern: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Model class:

```
namespace MyProjectNamespace.Data.ViewModels
{
    public class RegisterModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name ="Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Passwords do not match.")]
        public string  ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        public string CompanyID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show RegisterViewModel class?

Comment: @ShadiNamrouti I added the model class.

Comment: You are using `RegisterViewModel` but we only can see `RegisterModel` in your project?

Comment: Dont put any content inside `<div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger">`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, it is supposed to be RegisterViewModel but i changed the name of the model class later. I made it work but creating another project, not sure what was the problem with this one. I created another net core 3.1 mvc  but without razor pages project and same code worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Why are the fields NULL for the RegisterViewModel param in the controler?

It's strange and It works for me with code same as you. Please make sure the `Model` from `view` is same as model in `controller`.

> 2. Is it ok to use RAZOR PAGES and MVC VIEWS in the same project, a mix of them?

You can use `MVC` and `razor page` in the same project. You have already registered the razor page service in your project. Just create `Pages` folder in the project `root` directory, and then create a new Razor page file in this folder, right click this folder: `Add` -> `Razor Page`.

I tested before in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63099635/asp-net-core-applications-issue-with-razor-and-mvc-pages/63111024#63111024).

> 3. Why are the tag helpers (such as "asp-for") not colored green by the Intellisense (The are blue instead in Register.chtml)?

It depends on the version of your VS.

For VS 2015, here is [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40924211/net-core-tag-helper-intellisense-and-color-coding-not-working) from @Murat SEKER

1. Install `Razor tool` from package manager console.

   Install-Package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools`
2. Download and install [Razor Language Services](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-madsk.RazorLanguageServices) from marketplace. (Your visual studio instance should be closed)

After restart visual studio, `intellisense` and coloring should be working for tag helpers.

[image]